# Google Analytics for Mobile Websites not tracking data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, google-analytics, mobile-website

Has anyone ran into this issue?

We have a mobile site that can't use JavaScript based tracking for Google Analytics, so we have to use the solution found here: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/#asp

However, it doesn't appear to be logging any data over the last few days.

This is the code being used:

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsHelpers
{
    public static String GetTrackingImageUrl()
    {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.Append("/ga.aspx?");
        url.Append("utmac=").Append(Configuration.GoogleAnalyticsKey());

        Random randomClass = new Random();
        url.Append("&utmn=").Append(randomClass.Next(0x7fffffff));

        String referer = "-";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null && "" != HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
        {
            referer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        }
        url.Append("&utmr=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referer));

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url != null)
        {
            url.Append("&utmp=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
        }

        url.Append("&guid=ON");

        return url.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
    }
}
```

And in the ga.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="image/gif"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography"%>
<script runat="server" language="c#">
  /**
    Copyright 2009 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  **/

  // Tracker version.
  private const string Version = "4.4sa";

  private const string CookieName = "__utmmobile";

  // The path the cookie will be available to, edit this to use a different
  // cookie path.
  private const string CookiePath = "/";

  // Two years in seconds.
  private readonly TimeSpan CookieUserPersistence = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(63072000);

  // 1x1 transparent GIF
  private readonly byte[] GifData = {
      0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
      0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
      0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
      0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
  };

  private static readonly Regex IpAddressMatcher =
      new Regex(@"^([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.).*");

  // A string is empty in our terms, if it is null, empty or a dash.
  private static bool IsEmpty(string input) {
    return input == null || "-" == input || "" == input;
  }

  // The last octect of the IP address is removed to anonymize the user.
  private static string GetIP(string remoteAddress) {
    if (IsEmpty(remoteAddress)) {
      return "";
    }
    // Capture the first three octects of the IP address and replace the forth
    // with 0, e.g. 124.455.3.123 becomes 124.455.3.0
    Match m = IpAddressMatcher.Match(remoteAddress);
    if (m.Success) {
      return m.Groups[1] + "0";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  // Generate a visitor id for this hit.
  // If there is a visitor id in the cookie, use that, otherwise
  // use the guid if we have one, otherwise use a random number.
  private static string GetVisitorId(
      string guid, string account, string userAgent, HttpCookie cookie) {

    // If there is a value in the cookie, don't change it.
    if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null) {
      return cookie.Value;
    }

    String message;
    if (!IsEmpty(guid)) {
      // Create the visitor id using the guid.
      message = guid + account;
    } else {
      // otherwise this is a new user, create a new random id.
      message = userAgent + GetRandomNumber() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    byte[] sum = md5.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    string md5String = BitConverter.ToString(sum);
    md5String = md5String.Replace("-","");

    md5String = md5String.PadLeft(32, '0');

    return "0x" + md5String.Substring(0, 16);
  }

  // Get a random number string.
  private static String GetRandomNumber() {
    Random RandomClass = new Random();
    return RandomClass.Next(0x7fffffff).ToString();
  }

  // Writes the bytes of a 1x1 transparent gif into the response.
  private void WriteGifData() {
    Response.AddHeader(
        "Cache-Control",
        "private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate");
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.AddHeader("Expires", "Wed, 17 Sep 1975 21:32:10 GMT");
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
  }

  // Make a tracking request to Google Analytics from this server.
  // Copies the headers from the original request to the new one.
  // If request containg utmdebug parameter, exceptions encountered
  // communicating with Google Analytics are thown.
  private void SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(string utmUrl) {
    try {
      WebRequest connection = WebRequest.Create(utmUrl);

      ((HttpWebRequest)connection).UserAgent = Request.UserAgent;
      connection.Headers.Add("Accepts-Language",
          Request.Headers.Get("Accepts-Language"));

      using (WebResponse resp = connection.GetResponse()) {
        // Ignore response
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      if (Request.QueryString.Get("utmdebug") != null) {
        throw new Exception("Error contacting Google Analytics", ex);
      }
    }
  }

  // Track a page view, updates all the cookies and campaign tracker,
  // makes a server side request to Google Analytics and writes the transparent
  // gif byte data to the response.
  private void TrackPageView() {
    TimeSpan timeSpan = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime());
    string timeStamp = timeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString();
    string domainName = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
    if (IsEmpty(domainName)) {
      domainName = "";
    }

    // Get the referrer from the utmr parameter, this is the referrer to the
    // page that contains the tracking pixel, not the referrer for tracking
    // pixel.
    string documentReferer = Request.QueryString.Get("utmr");
    if (IsEmpty(documentReferer)) {
      documentReferer = "-";
    } else {
      documentReferer = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(documentReferer);
    }
    string documentPath = Request.QueryString.Get("utmp");
    if (IsEmpty(documentPath)) {
      documentPath = "";
    } else {
      documentPath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(documentPath);
    }

    string account = Request.QueryString.Get("utmac");
    string userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
    if (IsEmpty(userAgent)) {
      userAgent = "";
    }

    // Try and get visitor cookie from the request.
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(CookieName);

    string visitorId = GetVisitorId(
        Request.Headers.Get("X-DCMGUID"), account, userAgent, cookie);

    // Always try and add the cookie to the response.
    HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName);
    newCookie.Value = visitorId;
    newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now + CookieUserPersistence;
    newCookie.Path = CookiePath;
    Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);

    string utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";

    // Construct the gif hit url.
    string utmUrl = utmGifLocation + "?" +
        "utmwv=" + Version +
        "&utmn=" + GetRandomNumber() +
        "&utmhn=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(domainName) +
        "&utmr=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentReferer) +
        "&utmp=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentPath) +
        "&utmac=" + account +
        "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" +
        "&utmvid=" + visitorId +
        "&utmip=" + GetIP(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

    SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(utmUrl);

    // If the debug parameter is on, add a header to the response that contains
    // the url that was used to contact Google Analytics.
    if (Request.QueryString.Get("utmdebug") != null) {
      Response.AddHeader("X-GA-MOBILE-URL", utmUrl);
    }
    // Finally write the gif data to the response.
    WriteGifData();
  }
</script><% TrackPageView(); %>
```

Has anyone run into this issue? Where can I go to find out why nothing is being tracked? It's only tracked 2 visits over the last few days. FWIW, the status in Google Analytics for that site does have a green check mark and appears to be working fine.

Thanks for any help you can give!

UPDATE: More info:

It appears it's tracking as *1* person. All the views are there it looks like (i.e. the page views are tracking). I wonder if it's because the web server is serving the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into Google Analytics page settings for our app, and dug down into settings, then into status, then into advanced, then changed the radio button to mobile site. From there, it looks like we're to use a different account number for a mobile website app! That is, instead of your typical UA based account number, the UA must be swapped with MO. That should fix it!